# What is the fastest way to transpose and normalize the data in an ndarray containing multiple images?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a 'batch' of images, usually 128 that are initially read into a numpy array of dimensions 128x360x640x3. I need to transpose each image from NHWC to NCHW, thus an operation of `ndarray.transpose(2,0,1)` and also normalize the pixels to a [0,1] range, thus I need to divide the array by 255. This batch processing operation will be repeated periodically perhaps a hundred or so times. The simplest implementation for this looks like this:

```
for i in range(128):
    batchImageDataNew[i,:,:] = batchImageData[i,:,:].transpose(2,0,1)/255.
```

batchImageDataNew is of type np.float32 whereas batchImageData is np.uint8. I am trying to speed this process up as much as possible. I thought `ndarray.transpose` only rearranges the strides without actually touching the memory, but I see approximately ~1 ms per image for just the transpose (120ms in total). On the other hand, doing both the transpose and the division brings up the total time to about 350ms. What would be the best way to speed this up as much as possible? Would a combination of Cython and multi(threading?)processing help? I am working on Ubuntu where I have access to OpenMP as well.

EDIT: I tried a simple multiprocessing.Pool implementation which gave me about 270ms for the whole loop, but I'd like to optimize it even further.

```
def preprocess(i):
    batchImageDataNew[i,:,:] = batchImageData[i,:,:].transpose(2,0,1)/255.


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
pool.map(preprocess, range(128))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is highly memory and cache dependend. The optimal solution will depend on your processor and RAM-speed. This is a solution using Numba, but you can do a quite similar aproach using cython.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time


def tran_scal(batchImageData):
  s=batchImageData.shape
  batchImageDataNew=np.empty((s[0],s[3],s[1],s[2]),dtype=np.float32)
  for i in range(batchImageData.shape[0]):
    batchImageDataNew[i,:,:] = batchImageData[i,:,:].transpose(2,0,1)/255.
  return batchImageDataNew


@nb.njit()
def tran_scal_nb(batchImageData):
  s=batchImageData.shape
  batchImageDataNew=np.empty((s[0],s[3],s[1],s[2]),dtype=np.float32)
  for i in range(batchImageData.shape[0]):
    for j in range(batchImageData.shape[1]):
      for k in range(batchImageData.shape[2]):
        for l in range(batchImageData.shape[3]):
          batchImageDataNew[i,l,j,k] = batchImageData[i,j,k,l]*(1/255.)
  return batchImageDataNew

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def tran_scal_nb_p(batchImageData):
  s=batchImageData.shape
  batchImageDataNew=np.empty((s[0],s[3],s[1],s[2]),dtype=np.float32)
  for i in nb.prange(batchImageData.shape[0]):
    for j in range(batchImageData.shape[1]):
      for k in range(batchImageData.shape[2]):
        for l in range(batchImageData.shape[3]):
          batchImageDataNew[i,l,j,k] = batchImageData[i,j,k,l]*(1/255.)
  return batchImageDataNew
```

**Timings**

```
Core i7-4xxx
#Test data
data=np.array(np.random.rand(128,360,640,3)*255,dtype=np.uint8)
Your solution:    550ms
@wwii(transpose): 379ms
tran_scal_nb:     190ms 
tran_scal_nb_p:   100ms
```

On the first call there is a compilation overhead of about 0.5s, which is not included in the timings.

Comment: I am working on a Jetson TX2 (ARM processor), so it's not exactly the greatest. I will test out your solution: would Cython be faster than this (closer to pure C for example)?

Comment: It is all about cache usage. I don't know, which is the fastest on your platform, but I would try quite the same in Cython. What do you mean with "Cython or closer to pure C example" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: I was wondering if Cython's performance would be close to what one would expect from doing this in pure C. I'll definitely try it out

Comment: I'm curious: see my edit, do your timings show the same improvement?

Comment: @wwii I see a performance benefit of 11%.  If I put the memory allocation outside the benchmarking loop (only for testing, this only makes sence if you have a memory buffer and you process image by image) there is a 45% improvement in your function. I testet my tran_scal_nb_p also with memory allocation outside the performance testing loop (giving 50%). The 40-50% if not testing memory allocation doesn't supprise me that much (memory allocation is quite costly), but the 11-25% in your edited example really do. Maybe the weird behaivour of the garbage collector?

Comment: .. I can't find anything more specific than the `Tip` after [this ufunc list](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/ufuncs.html#math-operations) - maybe if it has a place to put results they can stream right into it rather than creating a temporary space that eventually is assigned to a name??  Creating the out array is really insignificant on my machine, about 1/10000 of the total calc.

Comment: I am a little confused as to how to implement this: does the @nb.njit specification go above the function definition? When I call these functions, I am actually seeing more time taken for the numba parallelized functions (trying on an i5-6600)

Comment: On the first time you call the function, the function gets compiled (Quite the same as compiling a C-Code, but types are determined from the input arrays). The parallelized version takes more time to compile than the single threaded  version. The second call and all subsequent calls are much faster than the first call. You can avoid the recompilation on every restart of Python if you use the keyword cache=True (not working if you have a python instance open and copy the code in the input window and also not working with the parallelized version, but will hopefully supported soon)

Answer (score 1):

Fake data

```
a = np.array([[[1,1]],[[2,2]],[[3,3]]])
b = a + 10
c = b + 10
d = c + 10
e = np.stack((a,b,c,d))
```

Usually better to avoid for loops if you can and operate on the whole array

```
f = np.transpose(e, (0,3,1,2))
g = f / 255

>>> e.shape
(4, 3, 1, 2)
>>> f.shape
(4, 2, 3, 1)
```

Or `np.moveaxis` instead of `transpose`

```
f = np.moveaxis(e, 3, 1)
f = np.moveaxis(e, (1,2,3), (2,3,1))
```

---

A slight ~25% improvement (on my machine) can be achieved by creating an array beforehand to accept the result of the division:

```
a = np.array(np.random.rand(128,360,640,3)*255,dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.zeros((128,3,360,640), dtype=np.float32)
np.divide(np.moveaxis(a, (1,2,3), (2,3,1)), 255, out=b)
```